# How can we customize layer 7 load balancers in K8s Ingress to map between TCP and REST messages?

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, traefik-ingress

Do we have layer 7 ingress load balancers in K8s which allows us to customize the default load balancers.
We have a use case where the ingress load balancer shall receive messages over TCP from few clients, and send out REST/gRPC messages on other side. (opposite also shall happen)

This way the load balancer allows to map/interwork between TCP and REST. It should receive tcp packet, read its content and locally create a JSON query over REST with the content it read.

We tried checking for NGINX and Traefik LB's so far, however still looking if they allow customization of the level we need.